# How to select every nth record?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select a specific set of records which should work like this:

query 1 should select ID's = 1,2,3 skip 4 - 5,6,7 skip 8 - 9,10,11 skip 12 and so on.
query 2 should select only every 4th ID = 4,8,12,16 and so on.

I found this code to select every 4th record:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, noun
    FROM (
        SELECT @row :=0) r, nouns
    ) ranked
WHERE rownum %4 =1
```

I didn't test it yet, but I will just assume that it works, but how can I do the first query ?

Thanks

Comment: `WHERE rownum %4 != 1` ?

Comment: Are you skipping 4 to 5 or just 4? What does the minus sign mean in your notation?

Comment: Just 4, basically select 3 skip 4 select 3 again and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table where id mod 4 <> 0
```

Comment: This will work assuming there are no gaps in the ids. This might not be the case of rows have been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, noun
    FROM (
        SELECT @row :=0) r, nouns
    ) ranked
WHERE rownum %4 =1
```

will select the (0th,) 4th, 8th, .. row. In analogous way you can select the others:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, noun
    FROM (
        SELECT @row :=0) r, nouns
    ) ranked
WHERE rownum %4 <> 1
```

This SQL could be shortened to

```
SELECT
    @row := @row +1 AS rownum, noun
FROM
  (SELECT @row :=0) r,
  nouns
WHERE (@row % 4) [=|<>] 1
```

This could be quite significant, as I suspect MySQL will use a temp table on the long form but not on the shorter form (not verified)