# How to skip n rows (i += n) in MySQL results?

Tags: mysql

Imagine I have a table with column value with perfectly ordered rows 1 till 100.

How do i skip 5 rows in the the results instead of 1, 2, 3... I got 1, 6, 11, 16...

Is this thing even possible?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779503/how-to-select-every-nth-record

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8 or later?

Answer (score 1):

Using [modulo operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) you can achieve such result.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id % 5 = 1
```

[It can be written in three forms](https://database.guide/mysql-mod-function-perform-a-modulo-operation-in-mysql/)

```
MOD(N,M) => select * from table where mod(id, 5) = 1
N % M  => as shown above
N MOD M => select * from table where (id mod 5) = 1
```

Comment: didn't read until end :) but fixed however

Comment: Thank you very much! A question: It works for the perfect records, but how do i used this technique on non perfect records if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: man I'm confused with stackoverflow comment system.

Comment: what are perfect and non perfect records?

Comment: If i filter the records, the value would be 1, 7, 8, 30, 80, 100, 199 and so on. How do I keep the output to still skip 5 rows (1, 100 so on).

Comment: plz create a fiddle with your input and desired outputs. it's hard to decide what your original intent is.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question this is a job for [MOD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod).

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE (id MOD 5) = 1
```

You asked about *imperfect ordering*. I believe you mean a situation where some `id` values are missing.  For example, if you have

```
1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

you want a result of

```
1  7 12
```

The answer to that question depends on the version of MySQL you use.  If you have a "modern" version (MySQL 8+, MariaDB 10+) you can use a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) to get the [row number](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number), then use MOD.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT  *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rownum
         FROM  table
) a
WHERE rownum MOD 5 = 1
```

If you're using a more primitive version of MySQL you can fake the ROW_NUMBER window function with session variables.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
              SELECT detail.*,
                    (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS rownum
               FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id) detail
               JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS init
            ) a
WHERE rownum MOD 5 = 1
```

This query is more painful to write because you must apply ORDER BY to the rows of your detail table before you do the @row_number work. Hence the doubly nested SELECT queries.

Comment: If i filter the records, the value would be 1, 7, 8, 30, 80, 100, 199 and so on. How do I keep the output to still skip 5 rows (1, 100 so on).